# Массив объектов

Tags: массивы, объекты, c++

Пытаюсь запихнуть в каждый элемент массива касса B массив класса A( объекты генерируются специальной процедурой), но почему то в массив класса B постоянно попадает один и тот же массив (т.е. процедура не выполняет свою работу). Помогите найти ошибку:

```
Cut* cArray = new Cut[20];
Rhombus* rArray = new Rhombus[10];

void CutArray(int xCenter,int yCenter,int vSize,int hSize) // vSize 40  hSize 80
{
    // код генерации массива
}

void RhombusArray(int xCenter,int yCenter,int vSize,int hSize,int height)
{
    int temp;
    int vStep = height/10;
    int hStep = 2;
    int StartX = xCenter + hStep*5;
    int StartY = yCenter - vStep*5;
    for(temp = 0; temp < 10; temp++)
    {
        CutArray(StartX,StartY,vSize,hSize);
        StartX=StartX - hStep;
        StartY=StartY + vStep;
        rArray[temp]->Array = cArray;
    }
}
```

Когда я вызываю CutArray для заполнения массива для объекта Rhombus, все работает как надо, но при вызове RhombusArray генерируются одинаковые массивы

```
    Dot* A = new Dot(50,50);
Dot* B = new Dot(70,70);
Cut* C= new Cut(A,B);
CutArray(200,200,40,120);
Rhombus Rh(cArray);
RhombusArray(400,100,40,80,150);
PrismRhombus Pr(rArray);
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что _весь_ этот код нужен читателям? Попробуйте выкинуть всё лишнее из примера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема — использование глобальных переменных. Просто не делайте так, это практически всегда неправильно.

Смотрите. Вы записываете в `rArray[0]->Array` указатель на заполненный **глобальный** массив `cArray`. На следующей итерации вы меняете данные в **том же самом** глобальном массиве, и записываете в `rArray[1]->Array` **тот же самый** указатель. И так далее.

Таким образом, вы 10 раз меняете данные в одном и том же глобальном массиве, и 10 раз запоминаете указатель на этот глобальный массив в `rArray`.

Выкиньте глобальные переменные раз и навсегда. Заводите каждый раз новый массив, ни в коем случае не передавайте его через глобальную переменную, позаботьтесь о своевременном выделении и уничтожении памяти. Будет работать.

Comment: Точно, огромное спасибо, о том область памяти на глобальный массив не меняется я совсем забыл. О выделении и уничтожении памяти тоже позабочусь

Comment: @Frnk: Пожалуйста!